# How to handle choosing the corrupted images form Gallery as it leads to UIImagePickerController Crashing

Tags: objective-c, swift

I want to verify the image being picked form the phone gallery is normal image or Corrupted image?, If the image is corrupted it is returning nil which leads to app crash when the choose button is clicked. Kindly someone help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance...!

Edit :

When the Corrupted Image is selected i am not getting the call back to this delegate method

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) imagePicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;
{
 if ([info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] == nil) {
    NSLog(@"The image selected is Corrupted");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    }];

}
```

Please help me out to fix this..

Comment: You may wish to show some code.  If it's crashing in the image picker itself, there's probably nothing you can do.

Comment: Validate the image before you do something with it `if (image) ...`